# How do you bring back improvised turrets?

Tags: rimworld

I brought along a steel improvised turret (weighing 100kg) when I went to attack a pirate base.

When I attempted a retreat, I uninstalled it so I could bring it back with me, but I cannot pick it up due to the reason that it is "Too Heavy" as it exceeds a person's maximum carrying capacity, despite the fact a single person was able to carry the turret into the pirates base.

Is there any way to bring it back with me short of deconstructing it?

Answer (score 2):

Each colonist and animal has an informational page you may look at to find their maximum carrying capacity. From that menu, you can see if anyone is capable of lifting 100kg. A colonists manipulation stat will affect their hauling capacity, either decreasing or increasing it. If I remember correctly, some prosthetics may increase manipulation above the normal amount. The two mechanites diseases also increase manipulation.

You would need a person with the proper stats to carry this item. Alternatively you can train an animal to haul it, such as an elephant which has a capacity of 300kg. Unless one is trained already, it is most likely faster to deconstruct and reconstruct elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you clear the area of enemies, you can carry heavy items out of the area when you reform the caravan.

I ran across this same scenario when investigating an item stash. You can't simply pick up the item you want, because it's too heavy for any individual to carry. However, if the weight of the item and all your other items is less than the maximum carrying weight of your caravan, you can pick up the item when you reform the caravan. The only downside to this is that you will need to clear the area of any enemies first.